# Given a logistic regression curve, How to select the data points which will result in the given curve?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have special problem at hand, I know the logistic regression I want (i.e. I know the parameters for the curve), I want to select the data points (independent and dependent variable) which will result in the given curve. it's okay to remove the some data points, but I want to remove the least number of data points. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: [This?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46525/247274)